# How to set npm credentials using `npm login` without reading from stdin?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-publish, npm-login

I'm trying to automate `npm publish` inside a Docker container, but I receive an error when the `npm login` command tries to read the username and email:

```sh
npm login << EOF
username
password
email
EOF
```

It works in a Bash terminal, but in a container (without `stdin`) it shows error:

```sh
Username: Password: npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

According to [npm-adduser](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-adduser.html):

> The username, password, and email are read in from prompts.

How can I run `npm login` without using `stdin`?

Comment: Your command actually worked for me, thanks! :) The only thing missing was to add the `--repository` parameter...

Comment: I myself are using the `_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}` in `.npmrc` today, which was not available back to 2014. Thanks to all the answers which makes me hesitate to mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 67):

```
npm set "//<registry>/:_authToken=$TOKEN"
```

Example for Github Package Registry:

```
npm set "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$GITHUB_TOKEN"
```

This is the simplest solution that I have found.

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Comment: note for github actions users: secrets are accessible via `${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }}`, thus you'll need to  `npm set "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken" ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN_OR_WHATEVER }}`

Comment: note for docker users: docker build may log the clear-text value of NPM_TOKEN to your console/ci logs. You can avoid this by putting this command into a `./npm-config.sh` and executing that instead.

Comment: I've bean searching for days for this. Thank you!

Comment: what is the difference between _authToken and _auth ?

Comment: I had luck with this. I just had to add = between _authToken og $TOKEN in TeamCity
[npm set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=$TOKEN]

Answer (score 55):

**TL;DR:** Make an HTTP request directly to the registry:

```sh
TOKEN=$(curl -s \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X PUT --data '{"name": "username_here", "password": "password_here"}' \
  http://your_registry/-/user/org.couchdb.user:username_here 2>&1 | grep -Po \
  '(?<="token": ")[^"]*')

npm set registry "http://your_registry"
npm set //your_registry/:_authToken $TOKEN
```

## Rationale

Behind the scenes `npm adduser` makes an HTTP request to the registry. Instead of forcing `adduser` to behave the way you want, you could make the request directly to the registry without going through the cli and then set the auth token with `npm set`.

[The source code suggests](https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client/blob/856eefea40a2a88618835978e281300e3406924b/lib/adduser.js#L63-L68) that you could make a PUT request to `http://your_registry/-/user/org.couchdb.user:your-username` with the following payload

```
{
  name: username,
  password: password
}
```

and that would create a new user in the registry.

Many thanks to @shawnzhu for having found a more cleaner approach to solve the problem.

Comment: This is clever but doesn't seems to work in my case. We're using ProGet and the output of that command see to only return and object like { "ok":"true" } and no tokens whatsoever. Seems like proget change the response from that command... I'll kept you posted if I found anything.

Comment: What if we just want to login, and not add a new user? I get bcak "user exists" with the above PUT request.

Comment: got the solution : https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/329#issuecomment-217406747

Comment: If you have already logged in with `npm login`, the information of the token can be found at file `~/.npmrc` in your home folder. Then, with only `npm set //your-registry.com/:_authToken="wKaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa="`

Comment: Has anyone else the problem that this solution is not working? I always get "You don't have permission to publish .."

Comment: For some reason the regex did not work for me on the new Github registry. This one fixed it:

`grep -oP "token\":\"\K\w+")`

Comment: This gives me an error of `user registration disabled` when using verdaccio...

Answer (score 17):

`npm-cli-login` allows you to log in to NPM without STDIN.

In order to install run:

`npm install -g npm-cli-login`

Example usage:

```
npm-cli-login -u Username -p Password -e test@example.com -r https://your-private-registry-link
```

Answer (score 16):

This worked in one of my devops flows

### Steps

1. Generate **_auth** from npm registry credentials with base 64 using shell for security:

```
    echo -n 'myuser:mypassword' | openssl base64
    Result will be something like : eWFob29vb2E=
```

2. Set npm registry url and _auth before **npm install ...**

```
    npm config set registry https://nexus-acme.com/repository/npm-group/
    npm config set _auth eWFob29vb2E=
```

That's all. You could run **npm install**, and your private modules will be downloaded.

### Note

- Nodejs offer the basic auth (user:password) as valid option:

  - [Using auth tokens in .npmrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099434/using-auth-tokens-in-npmrc)
  - [Give credentials to npm login command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540096/give-credentials-to-npm-login-command-line)
- With basic auth, the basic token is store usually in `~/.npmrc`
- This basic token is encoded with base64 so anyone with access to your machine, will easily decode and see your user:password. **If you are concern, ask to the nodejs creators why use this.**
- For developers and devops flows, is usual this strategy : maven (java), pip (python), nuget(c#), etc
- If you are concern to the store the secret in the developer machine, you should use some advanced npm packages registry like github in which an token (with expiration time) is provided. Anyway this token should be stored in the machine, so **there is no way** to stabilize a connection to the NPM Registry  **without login and/or without store the obtained token**
- A crazy option could be oauth2 with a web login on each npm install. I cannot imagine a devops automation (pure shell) in which on each npm install, the human sysadmin is required to perform a web login...
- For non interactive flows , secrets will always required in the server or developer machine.

Comment: this doesnt work for me at all... i have it in my .npmrc file and try npm install still authentication error.

Comment: what is your nodejs version? Delete the old .npmrc and try again!

Comment: Worked for me, to login to a Nexus private registry without any internet access.

Comment: FYI: Base64 isn't 'security' at all, it's obfuscation at best, and provides no security benefits.

Comment: Of course I know that. Maybe you could ask to the NPM creators why they continue offering this way.  Also you can use [2fa](https://docs.npmjs.com/accessing-npm-using-2fa) but that was not the question

Comment: If you know it's not secure then don't put "for security" in your answer.  Plus, there's no reason to do this when you could use a time-limited token and set `_authToken` to it instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate an answer?

Answer (score 14):

An expect script worked for me.  You need to make sure expect is installed, this command should do it for ubuntu:

```
apt-get install expect-dev
```

Your script could look something like this (npm_login_expect):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# set our args into variables
set i 0; foreach n $argv {set "p[incr i]" $n}

set timeout 60
#npm login command, add whatever command-line args are necessary
spawn npm login
match_max 100000

expect "Username"    
send "$p1\r"

expect "Password"
send "$p2\r" 

expect "Email"
send "$p3\r"

expect {
   timeout      exit 1
   eof
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
expect -f npm_login_expect myuser mypassword "myuser@domain.com"
```

Comment: Yes if there is tty that `expect` can read. my problem is, there's no STDIN nor sudo tty at all.

Comment: Worked a treat in a chef recipe as well.

Comment: I am getting error : `spawn npm login
 npm ERR! wrong # args: should be "eof channelId"
     while executing
 "eof"
     invoked from within
 "expect {
    timeout      exit 1
    eof
 }"
     (file "npm_login.sh" line 20)`

Answer (score 14):

I took a slightly different approach that seems to work great still. To begin with, you will need an auth token. This is easily obtainable by locally running `npm adduser` and then grabbing the generated token from your `~/.npmrc` located in your user folder. In order to be authenticated on your ci server this auth token needs to be appended to the registry URL in the user's `.npmrc` (similar to how it was locally), not the `.npmrc` located in the repo, so these worked great as script steps in my CI configuration

```
- echo "//<npm-registry>:8080/:_authToken=$AUTH_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
- npm publish
```

where AUTH_TOKEN is stored as a secret variable in your settings.
A good way to test this is to replace `npm publish` with `npm whoami` to test and make sure it successfully logged you in.

Here is my entire publish configuration

```
publish:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - yarn run build
    - echo "//<npm-registry>:8080/:_authToken=$NPME_AUTH_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
    - npm publish
    - echo 'Congrats on your publication!'
```

I'm using gitlab-ci but I don't see why this wouldn't apply to any ci application.

Comment: [`npm ping`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) has been set up precisely to allow testing connectivity and credentials. Also note that sometimes it's useful to output to a local `.npmrc` file instead of always putting it in the user's HOME folder—especially to avoid blowing up the user's normal day-to-day configuration just because some automation command was run.

Comment: Thanks @bryson I used this solution in github actions today

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to fetch the token and update the ~/.npmrc

```
export ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN=`curl --silent --show-error --fail -u $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME:$ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY https://artifactory.my.io/artifactory/api/npm/auth | \
grep -oP '_auth[\s?]=[\s?]\K(.*)$'`

echo "@my:registry=https://artifactory.my.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-release-local/" > ~/.npmrc
echo "//artifactory.my.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-release-local/:_auth=${ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN}" >> ~/.npmrc
echo "//artifactory.my.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-release-local/:email=${ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME}" >> ~/.npmrc
echo "//artifactory.my.io/artifactory/api/npm/npm-release-local/:always-auth=true" >> ~/.npmrc
```

This prevents issues with @scope package retrieval from npmjs

Answer (score 6):

`npm login` command stores all the credentials in the global `.npmrc` file. The pattern is not similar and it changes. Explained below:

There are TWO patterns, either one should work. NOTE: There may be other patterns in which npm stores the auth data, hence it's always better to cross-check the content of the `.npmrc` file in a global context.

Every time we do `npm login` an entry is made in `.npmrc` if it does not exist.

So the two pattern(I have copied the below lines from .npmrc)

//your_registry/:_authToken=amvasdfjkhjkjsdhflakjsdfhalskjh==
//your_registry/:_authToken=NpmToken.6ca7867aba-d66a-32c0-9srr-fba908987d7987f

So the only thing to do is to copy the line from global `.npmrc` and put it in local or project `.npmrc` and run the `npm publish` command from CI. Explicit `npm login` is not required.

Comment: I'd not recommend saving the actual auth token into `.npmrc`. use an environment variable like `//your_registry/:_authToken=${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}` would be better

Answer (score 3):

This builds on top of Alexander F's answer. This is just a simplified version of the code he provided, mashed up with the example code provided by [npm-registry-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-registry-client).

```
"use strict";

var RegClient = require('npm-registry-client')
var client = new RegClient()
var uri = "https://registry.npmjs.org/npm"
var params = {timeout: 1000}

var username = 'my.npm.username'
var password = 'myPassword'
var email = 'my.email@gmail.com'

var params = {
  auth: {
    username,
    password,
    email
  }
};

client.adduser(uri, params, function (error, data, raw, res) {
  if(error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`Login succeeded`);
  console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data,null,2)}`);
  console.log(`NPM access token: ${data.token}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**npm login** is an interactive method. So prefer using **npm-cli-login login**.

Follow the following steps:

```
               1. npm install -g npm-cli-login
               2. npm-cli-login login -u username -p password -e abc@gmail.com -r http://registry.npmjs.org
               3. npm publish src --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Here I want to publish the module to **http://registry.npmjs.org** and I have registered in it with my **emailid(abc@gmail.com)**, **username** and **password**

Answer (score 2):

Hard to believe that after all this time there is still no solution for npm login. Sure you can grab a token once and use it for all your CI needs, but what about the security implications of a never expiring token? And what if one day admins decide that tokens should expire?

Below is my hacky javascript solution using `npm-registry-client` package.  Just pass a json string argument and it will login and write an `.npmrc` file into your current dir. To log out use `npm logout` as usual.

```js
var client = new (require('npm-registry-client'))({});
var std_in = JSON.parse(process.argv[2]);

if (std_in.uri === undefined) {
    console.error('Must input registry uri!');
    return;
}

// fix annoying trailing '/' thing in registry uri
if (std_in.uri[std_in.uri.length - 1] !== '/') {
    std_in.uri = std_in.uri + '/';
}

if (std_in.scope === undefined) {
    console.error('Must input scope!');
    return;
    //std_in.scope = '@my-scope'; // or add default scope of your own
}

if (std_in.scope[0] !== '@') {
    std_in.scope = '@' + std_in.scope;
}

client.adduser(std_in.uri, std_in.params, function(err, data, raw, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    } 
    require('fs').writeFileSync('.npmrc', `${std_in.scope}:registry=${std_in.uri}\n//${(std_in.uri.split('//'))[1]}:_authToken=${data.token}`);
});
```

Example input:

```
{ 
    "uri": "https://my-nmp.reg",
    "scope": "@my-scope",
    "params": {
        "auth": {
            "username": "secret-agent",
            "password": "12345",
            "email": "secret-agent@007.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on `jq` and three ENV vars set:

```
export NPM_REGISTRY_DOMAIN=
export NPM_REGISTRY_USER=
export NPM_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=

json="{\"name\": \""$NPM_REGISTRY_USER"\", \"password\": \""$NPM_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"\"}"

TOKEN=$(curl -s \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -X PUT --data "$json" \
  --user "$NPM_REGISTRY_USER":"$NPM_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" \
  https://"$NPM_REGISTRY_DOMAIN"/-/user/org.couchdb.user:"$NPM_REGISTERY_USER" | \
            jq -r '.token'
    )

npm config set registry https://"$NPM_REGISTRY_DOMAIN"
npm set //"$NPM_REGISTRY_DOMAIN"/:_authToken "$TOKEN"
```

Based on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35831310/1663462

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem with my continuous delivery pipeline on gitlab. After sleepless nights and a short weekend the following one and only command worked for me:

```
npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

This basically updates the `.npmrc` in the **user** directory with the value of the token (and other values).

`NPM_TOKEN` is a (secret) environment variable with a value of a created token from the npm site.

Hope, that anybody can save time with this information. The npm documentation was not the best friend in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For the solution 2 exposed by [**ke_wa**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3480033/ke-wa) in this [duplicated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143973/npm-adduser-via-bash) has worked.

Mashup:

```
export NPM_USERNAME=mUs34
export NPM_PASSWORD=mypassW0rD
export NPM_EMAIL=user@domain.com
npm adduser<<!
$NPM_USERNAME
$NPM_PASSWORD
$NPM_EMAIL
!
```

Comment: Not working for me. I keep getting 
```Username: Password: npm ERR! cb() never called!```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using gitlab-ci for this.

but my private npm response without authtoken, so that the `npm-cli-login` can't run correctly.

i do a trick for my question, like this:

```js
 // If no entry for the auth token is found, add one
        if (authWrite === -1) {
            lines.push(args.registry.slice(args.registry.search(/\:\/\//, '') +
            1) + '/:_authToken=' + (args.quotes ? '"' : '') + response.token + (args.quotes ? '"' : ''));
        }
        // DIY
        var loginInfo = [
            {pass: '_password'},
            {user: 'username'},
            {email: 'email'}
        ]
        loginInfo.forEach(function(ele) {
            var key = Object.keys(ele);
            lines.push(args.registry.slice(args.registry.search(/\:\/\//, '') +
            1) + '/:' + ele[key] + '=' + (args.quotes ? '"' : '') + args[key] + (args.quotes ? '"' : ''));
        })
        // DIYend
        var toWrite = lines.filter(function (element) {
            if (element === '') {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

though it is foolish,but works

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the use of _auth to pass in the base64 processing of username and password is good, I wrote a publishing tool to solve this problem, I hope to help you;
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ausiliario

Answer (score -1):

You could use an expect script instead or write a node script that uses [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js).

Comment: Thanks. the root cause is `npm adduser` always ask for input from stdin which I can't make. Then I found another way which is kind of trick to generate a working `~/.npmrc`. see https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client/blob/master/lib/adduser.js#L71-L72

Comment: @shawnzu it'd be nice if you'd post the solution for the rest of the internet, as the link you gave uses master instead of a sha, so it's out of date now :(