# npm adduser via bash

Tags: bash, command-line, npm

I want to automate the npm login process via a bash script.

I tried it with this snippet:

```
/usr/bin/expect -f - <<EOD
spawn npm adduser
expect "Username:"
send "myUserName\n"
expect "mail: (this IS public)"
send "my@email.com\n"
EOD
```

But without luck.

*Note: I will change the strings with env variables*

Comment: for automation it may be better to set up the ~/.npmrc like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014522/442837

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up npm credentials over \`npm login\` without reading input from interactively from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460980/set-up-npm-credentials-over-npm-login-without-reading-input-from-interactively)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

@Aurélien Thieriot: thanks for the hint.

I have two solutions for my problem:

#### Solution 1

```sh
export NPM_AUTH_TOKEN=myToken
export NPM_EMAIL=myEmail
```

create/override `~/.npmrc` by following shell script:

```sh
echo "_auth = $NPM_AUTH_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
echo "email = $NPM_EMAIL" >> ~/.npmrc
```

#### Solution 2

```sh
export NPM_USERNAME=myUsername
export NPM_PASSWORD=myPassword
export NPM_EMAIL=myEmail
```

I know the order of the questions. So I can do the following:

```sh
npm adduser <<!
$NPM_USERNAME
$NPM_PASSWORD
$NPM_EMAIL
!
```

*Note: solution 2 works only when the user isn't added yet

Otherwise the `$NPM_PASSWORD` is not necessary*

Comment: For solution 1, I had to remove the `$` when I ran export.

Comment: For solution 2, remove $ when exporting.

Comment: I have removed $ from export command as per the other comments.

Answer (score 13):

This way works and with a more elegant **expect**:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn npm adduser
expect {
  "Username:" {send "$USERNAME\r"; exp_continue}
  "Password:" {send "$PASSWORD\r"; exp_continue}
  "Email: (this IS public)" {send "$EMAIL\r"; exp_continue}
}
EOD
```

Comment: maybe this can be done within one line? I have no idea how to put this to gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @holms, you can create a script with this content and run it via CI.
In my case I run it via Dockerfile:
  
    `ADD npm-login.sh $APP_HOME/npm-login.sh`  
    `RUN chmod +x $APP_HOME/npm-login.sh`  
    `RUN $APP_HOME/npm-login.sh`

Comment: I'm using gitlab-ci so I've ended up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062370/how-can-i-add-multi-line-bash-eod-command-to-gitlab-ci-yml/51079382#51079382

Answer (score 6):

For people working with a private registry (typically for CI purpose), reaching directly the Rest API may be a solution :

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "name": "your_username", "password": "your_password" }' 'http://localhost:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:your_username'
```

This is what `npm adduser` is doing behind the scene.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't have luck with any answers above on OSX.

This did work though:

```
npm install -g npm-cli-adduser
npm-cli-adduser -u username -p password -e email -r https://repo.com/nexus
```

Answer (score 3):

My Solution is to use plugin npm-login-cmd

```
npm install -g npm-login-cmd

export NPM_USER=user
export NPM_PASS=pass
export NPM_EMAIL=valid email syntax
npx npm-login-cmd
```

login work on enterprice npm repository

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is in any way secured so please do some research before.

But the fact is that `npm` is storing all those informations into a file. If you look at:

```
cat ~/.npmrc
```

It could be interesting enough so you could do the login dance only once.

Comment: Everyone knows in here that it's stored there, question how to have a single command for generating it. This is required for automation software like ansible and dockerfiles.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue but the only way of getting round it was to wrap expect into a docker image. You can use it like so:

```
docker run \
    -e NPM_USER=$NPM_USER \
    -e NPM_PASS=$NPM_PASS \
    -e NPM_EMAIL=$NPM_EMAIL \
    bravissimolabs/generate-npm-authtoken \
    > ~/.npmrc
```

https://github.com/bravissimolabs/docker-generate-npm-authtoken

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I no longer maintain that repo but it should still work.

Comment: It does indeed! we are using it atm :) ta

Answer (score 2):

I found that on Windows Server 2012R2, there is some odd behaviour with service accounts. This method worked for me (as part of a Jenkins build, under bash):

```
cat > ~/.npmrc <<EOL
//my.local.registry:4873/:_authToken="G....................A=="
always_auth=true
registry=http://my.local.registry:4873/
user=aRegisteredUser
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

using with npm-cli-login package it worked

```
# npm install -g npm-cli-login
# npm-cli-login -u myUser -p myPass -e t@ex.com -r http://192.168.56.1:4873
```

Checking if it is installed or not:

```
# whereis npm-cli-login
npm-cli-login:
# whereis npm-cli-login | grep '/npm-cli-login' -ic
0
```

After installation:

```
# npm install -g npm-cli-login
```

Check if it is installed:

```
# whereis npm-cli-login
npm-cli-login: /usr/bin/npm-cli-login
# whereis npm-cli-login | grep '/npm-cli-login' -ic
1
```

Let's login:

```
# npm-cli-login -u myUser -p myPass -e t@ex.com -r http://192.168.56.1:4873
info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:13:19 PM
http request PUT http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser
http 409 http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser
info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:13:19 PM
http request GET http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser?write=true
http 200 http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser?write=true
info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:13:20 PM
http request PUT http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser/-rev/undefined
http 201 http://192.168.56.1:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:myUser/-rev/undefined
#
# npm whoami
myUser
#
# npm logout
# npm whoami
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-21T22_13_42_373Z-debug.log
```

Comment: npm-cli-login depends on `snyk`, snyk downloads its own closed source binary 85MB from `https://static.snyk.io/cli/*/snyk-*`. It is too much for npm auto login, Carl =) I would go with expect instead.