# How can I add multi-line bash EOD command to gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: bash, yaml, gitlab-ci

This question been asked multiple times but most of them was easy to solve, although using tool `expect` it doesn't work as I've expected:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn npm adduser
expect {
  "Username:" {send "$USERNAME\r"; exp_continue}
  "Password:" {send "$PASSWORD\r"; exp_continue}
  "Email: (this IS public)" {send "$EMAIL\r"; exp_continue}
}
EOD
```

There's also more simple variant for the same purpose:

```
npm adduser <<!
$NPM_USERNAME
$NPM_PASSWORD
$NPM_EMAIL
!
```

.gitlab-ci.yml: this way it will produce one line string which is not good and command won't work

```
npm_push:
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - npm adduser <<!
      $NPM_USERNAME
      $NPM_PASSWORD
      $NPM_EMAIL
      !
    - npm config set registry https://$NPM_URL
    - npm push
```

How can I pass it in such way so that gitlab-runner execute this command in multi-line manner when passing it to bash?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it finally

```
npm_publish:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add expect git alpine-sdk python python-dev
    - npm config set registry https://$NPM_URL
    - npm install publish
    - |
        /usr/bin/expect <<EOD
        spawn npm adduser
        expect {
            "Username:" {send "$NPM_USERNAME\r"; exp_continue}
            "Password:" {send "$NPM_PASSWORD\r"; exp_continue}
            "Email: (this IS public)" {send "$NPM_EMAIL\r"; exp_continue}
        }
        EOD
```

Answer (score 2):

*This syntax is called `heredoc` in case anyone wants the proper name for further research.*

@holms found their solution already but I'd like to a add this [link](https://yaml-multiline.info/) to a helper for multi-line entries in YAML that covers the whole topic.
There are several ways to do multi-line entries in YAML. This tool helps find the one matching your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use YAML block syntax.

```
npm_push:
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
    - >
      npm adduser
      $NPM_USERNAME
      $NPM_PASSWORD
      $NPM_EMAIL
    - npm config set registry https://$NPM_URL
    - npm push
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#multiline-commands