# How should I use artifactory access token for access to npm repo

Tags: npm, access-token, artifactory

I would like to use an access token to publish and retrieve from an artifactory npm repo from a CI environment. I have created a Bearer token using the artifactory API but when I try and use that for access in the .npmrc with the format:

```
//mydomain.jrog.io/:_authToken=myveryverylongaccesstoken
registry=https://mydomain.jfrog.io/mydomain/api/npm/npm
```

I always receive 401 errors back.

In addition, though perhaps a different issue, if I try to use npm login with my actual artifactory credentials I get the response:

```
adduser Incorrect username or password
npm WARN adduser You can reset your account by visiting:
npm WARN adduser 
npm WARN adduser     https://npmjs.org/forgot
npm WARN adduser 
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! forbidden No oauth npm default login configuration found: org.couchdb.user:myusername
```

The artifactory docs around access tokens explicitly say this is the sort of use case to set up an access token, but the docs around setting up the npm repo alwyas seem to imply you need a real user account and make no mention of access tokens...

Answer (score 37):

What is your artifactory version?

The "npm login" way is only supported since 5.4 (aka. _authToken), so if you are below that, your only chance is to authenticate with BASIC authentication (aka. _auth).

Basic authentication is fairly easy to setup, Artifactory provides an easy entry point to help you set up your *.npmrc*

Launch the following (and do not forget to replace user and encrypted_password with the Artifactory user account you want to authenticate with)

`curl -u user:encrypted_password https://mydomain.jfrog.io/mydomain/api/npm/auth`

It will output something like

`_auth = YourLongBasicAuthToken
always-auth = true
email = user@server.com`

Copy these 3 lines in your *.npmrc*, and this should work well...

Comment: Thank you, this was very specifically my problem :)

Comment: can I use both somehow? my CI works only with `_auth` and my local setup `_authToken`. I suppose the difference is `npm` version? I tried to set both values simultaneously hoping this will help but it didnt

Comment: As note this worked generally, but npm complained at the _auth.  I had to change it to //artifactory.mycompany.net:8081/artifactory/api/npm/:_auth=<theToken> in my case.

Answer (score 8):

To generate the contents for `.npmrc`, use an existing user like admin with its password

`curl -uadmin:<PASSWORD> http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/npm/auth`

afterwards you can replace/set the `_auth` key with any base64 encoded `username:ACCESS_TOKEN`

for scoped packages, use

`curl -uadmin:<PASSWORD> http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/auth/<SCOPE>`

and set `..username` and `.._password` (base64) with any user and access token

Comment: Instead of password, you can also use an APIKey: 
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/npm-registry#:~:text=~/.npmrc-,Getting%20.npmrc%20entries%20directly%20from%20Artifactory,-Run%20the%20following

Answer (score 5):

1. **Using Basic Authentication**
   Using the next described steps you should change your local `.nprmc` file with the output of the command

- To retrieve the next fields `_auth`, `email` and `always-auth` automatically generated -> Run the following command to retrieve these strings directly from *Artifactory*:

> curl -u {username}:{API_key}
> http://{artifactory_server_domain}/{domain}/artifactory/api/npm/auth

Notes:

- {username} -> [Name near `Welcome` when you are logged in - take a look at the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThsNz.png)
- {Api_key} -> [Copy and paste this key - take a look at the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phvE4.png)
- {artifactory_server_domain} - domain of your artifactory accrodingly.
- {domain} - additional filed of domain in you url (if present)
- [Screenshot describes {artifactory_server_domain} and {domain}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQOvp.png)

Answer (score 2):

The _auth line in the other answers breaks some scoped package retrieval from npmjs.  I found that I needed to use specific _auth for just the one registry I was using.  See my original answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014522/442837

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the previously offered solutions:

```
curl -u username:encrypted_password http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/npm/auth >> ~/.npmrc
curl -u username:personal_api_key http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>/artifactory/api/npm/auth >> ~/.npmrc
```

here is another option without using curl (*does not work with API key):

```
npm config set _auth $(echo -n username:encrypted_password | base64)
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience adds to the comments made by others.

I was working with jfrog and already placed the package in jfrog. When trying to resolve that using jfrog.

I got the error "npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"" when i checked logs.

After spending hours trying to resolve.
I came across the documentation.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-ConfiguringthenpmClientforaScopeRegistry

This is very useful..The issue is I'm just pasting the access token instead of base64 encoded one.
[the helpful part of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsFpp.jpg)

Then I ran that command curl -u admin with a new credentials and token and got back the base64 encoded one.

Then it started working ..Hope it's helpful to anyone working with jfrog

Answer (score -7):

**For windows user :-**

1/ Add **https://registry.npmjs.org** to .npmrc to user profile on top:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

or 2/ Run below command

```
npm config set registry  https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: The user is asking how to deal with auth issues to his private npm repository. Switching to the public npm registry is not an option for a lot of developers coz there's private IP stored in private npm repos.