# Give credentials to npm login command line

Tags: shell, npm, command-line, terminal, npm-login

I need to pass the credentials for `npm login` in a script. Is there a way to give the credentials similar to the git credentials?

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found an npm package for this:

Install [npm-cli-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cli-login) and in the terminal/scripts use it as below:

```
npm-cli-login -u testUser -p testPass -e test@example.com
```

---

I found two other ways to pass the credentials without the need to use an external command, but be aware that these commands might not work in environments such as Jenkins.

Commands:

```bash
# First way
echo -e 'USERNAME\nPASSWORD\nEMAIL' | npm login -e EMAIL -r REGISTRY

# Second way
npm login -e EMAIL -r REGISTRY << EOF
USERNAME
PASSWORD
EMAIL
EOF
```

Comment: This modifies the .npmrc file under the hood, not sure this is the actual solution more so an option for not modifying the .npmrc file yourself. The .npmrc file is where credentials are actually managed.

Comment: The option that is preferred is native way so so first option need to be presented at the end. Then you show the first way and the second way, but the second way is clearly better to use for common types of users. SO i thin there is many cases, people is passing by your answer try the two first options and stop there lol...

Comment: I get

`Username: myusername
Password: npm ERR! cb() never called!`

Not sure if this is a problem with this method or a local issue with my npm installation.

Comment: Same issue, different error message: `Password: npm ERR! Exit handler never called!`

Comment: the npm-cli-login has not been updated for 2 + years and is incompatible with >=node18. Stick with npm login or piping to it.

Comment: @Brennan I get the same error. I suspect it is caused by an EOF being sent after the input which causes npm to abort. I have not found a way  to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 25):

Take a look at the `.npmrc` [file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) you can use this file to set npm configuration variables, such as credentials, registry location, etc... This file is located in your **HOME** directory. Here is an example `.npmrc` file to use for reference:

**~/.npmrc**

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
_auth="<token>"
email=<email>
always-auth=true
```

*substitute your email and _auth [token](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-viewing-authentication-tokens) appropriately for your credentials*. Your script will use these global configurations set within your `.npmrc` file.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: didn't downvote, but doesn't seem to work :( and there should be CLI options to override what's in npmrc anyway, and if there are not, that is NPM's decision

Comment: This used to work for me with node 12 but no longer seems to work with node 16

Comment: .nvmrc is not read when we do `npm install`....any reason for that ? Does it override the npm configs we've globally ? seems not working ! Currently what I can do is just change the version by using `nvm use`

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540693/6191913 This anwser is working.

To be more helpful, when you type `npm login` and give username and password interactively, npm will generate an auth_token automatically for you and insert it into the .npmrc.

The auth_token is constant given the username/password is the same.

For cli usage, you can just `echo //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_MY_TOKEN > ~/.npmrc` instead of `npm login ...`

Answer (score -4):

Typing `npm login` from the command line and entering your credentials will automatically generate an npm token and setup your .npmrc file for you.

Comment: OP is asking for a method to pass the credentials in as part of a script; `npm login` requires human input.