# How do I log in using only the CLI?

Tags: npm-login

I'm using the following environment with WSL2.

```
❯ npm -version
10.0.0

❯ node -v
v20.6.0

❯ cat /etc/debian_version
12.1
```

I tried `npm login` and got the following error.

```
❯ npm login
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
Login at:
https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/24c20e4f-67dc-4103-af15-95776747623c
Press ENTER to open in the browser...
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
The "file" argument must be of type string.
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stdin')

A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/masyuko0222/.npm/_logs/2023-09-07T12_55_35_293Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm having trouble understanding what this `The "file" argument` refers to.

Or is the error occurring because you are trying to open the browser from WSL2?
If so, should I try downgrading the npm version?

Please advise.

I've tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540693/6191913)

Comment: The crazy thing is, the browser opens and goes to the right site and lets you log in and and everything... but then nothing happens because it can't send the auth token back to the command line. How did no one notice the completely broken login flow?

Answer (score 4):

Try using legacy auth-type for login from CLI

```
npm login --auth-type legacy
```

Comment: It seems weird that we have to do that now... they added a non-legacy option by default but it's just broken? What's even the point of this new broken auth option?

Comment: That being said, this answer is the only solution and should be accepted.