# Authentication error on publishing to private NPM repository on Nexus

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus

I am having authentication problem when publishing to my private npm registry hosted on my private Nexus.

My Nexus setup is I have **npm-proxy**, **npm-registry** (hosted npm with `allowRepublish=false`), **npm-snapshots** (hosted npm with `allowRepublish=true`) and **npm-public** (group with all other three repositories).

Since I am developing a library, I am using my snapshot repository, so I can redeploy same version constantly (something like snapshot in maven world).

In my library project I have set this option in **package.json**

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots/"
}
```

Next, I created **.npmrc** file with following content:

```
registry=https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-public/
_auth=RVhBTVBMRQ==
```

And with this setup I can publish project with no problem. However, what bothers me, is that I have my password (which is just base64 encoded) stored in file, that should be commited, but I can't commit it, due to credentials in it.

I have tried to instead login to npm registry and removed the auth line from .npmrc
`npm adduser --registry=https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots --always-auth`

I got response `Logged in as myusername on https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots.`

However, when I try to run `npm publish` I get:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 6867ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-30T19_31_01_598Z-debug.log
```

Now in my other project (which is using this library), I simply created .npmrc file with content `registry=https://nexus.mjamsek.com/repository/npm-public/` and run command `npm adduser --registry=https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-public --always-auth` and I was able to download the published package.

However, the publish still won't work and I don't know why.

EDIT 31.7.2019: On my list of active realms I also have **npm Bearer Token Realm**

Comment: You need a trailing slash on the end of the registry URL passed into "npm adduser", otherwise npm will chop off the last segment of the URL, and it won't work.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, thank you. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need a trailing slash on the end of the registry URL passed into `npm adduser`, otherwise `npm` will chop off the last segment of the URL, and it won't work.

Comment: Answer of the YEAR! +100000000000000000000000

Answer (score 55):

When you do `npm login` or `npm adduser` the NPM client creates an authentication token that will be used in future request to the registry. Default NXRM configuration allows only *Local Authenticating Realm* which doesn't recognise NPM's token. Please make sure you have *npm Bearer Token Realm* active.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I already have this on list of active realms, I updated the question.

Comment: image is not available

Answer (score 8):

`_auth=` replaced with output of `btoa('username:userpassword')` and it worked for me.

I did use this btoa from chrome as below.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem today, my solution was to delete all registry entry from my npmrc file:

`registry=https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots/`

Idealy delete anything superfluous, back it up before-hand, in my case my file contained only:

`strict-ssl=false`

Then you can
`npm login --registry=https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-public/` again.

If that's not working, you also bypass npm login with curl, look at [this life saving post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460980/set-up-npm-credentials-over-npm-login-without-reading-input-from-interactively#35831310).

Comment: This is important if you work with multiple repositories.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the _auth token is correct. In my case I changed my system credentials and forgot to generate new _auth token. I was getting the exact same error i.e.
*"npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"*

once i fixed it, the issue was resolved.
For those who are looking for the command to generate _auth. It is:
***btoa('username:userpassword')***

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, my solution was to delete my global .npmrc file, and after login npm login.

Comment: This was the one that did it for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had ended with three versions of node on my machine. It turned out that the ones i installed later had their own local .npmrc files in the node_modules folders. They didn't use the global .npmrc even after i removed the local one so i had to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you have a repository setup in Nexus which contains:

- Hosted (repo for your private packages)
- Proxy (proxy to public packages, e.g. https://registry.npmjs.org)
- Group (group for the other 2 repos. Nexus will automatically forward requests to public packages to the proxy, and private packages to the hosted)

Like this: [Nexus Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVZFF.png)

In my usecase I needed to include the auth-configuration twice for **hosted and group** to make it work.

```
registry=https://my-private-nexus/repository/npm-group/
email=email@domain.com
always-auth=true
//my-private-nexus/repository/npm-group/:_auth=<auth-token>
//my-private-nexus/repository/npm-hosted/:_auth=<auth-token>
```

Successfully tested with node v18.16.0, npm 9.5.1, Nexus OSS 3.53.1-02

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling about this problem last two days, finally the solution was to delete .npmrc file from root (user) directory.
When npm tried to login, it used the creds inside this file and ignore your pass login.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. For me it was a problem with using registry such as "`https://my.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots/`" but having a different nexus reference in `package-lock.json`: "`https://some.previous.nexus.com/repository/npm-snapshots/`".

I found it after double checking the debug log. Removing `package-lock.json` helped in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar issue. I also have our credentials stored in an npmrc file in my user directory. When set up with node16/npm7, I would receive the error

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

If I use nvm to downgrade to node12/npm6, it works. I'd prefer a working solution without downgrading, but for now it lets me move on.

**UPDATE:**

We finally figured it out (a while ago, but I forgot about this answer). In our .npmrc files in our user directories, we needed to add/change our authorization config entry.

Before:
`_auth={base64 encoded username:password}`

After:
`//{path to private repository}:_auth={base64 encoded username:password}`

Comment: any updates? :/

Answer (score -3):

Just enable **anonymous** access in the nexus dashboard, it will pull from your private registry.

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of private registry