# NPM Publish error: You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-publish

I am trying to run `npm publish` on a package after I've upgraded to `node v18` and `npm v9`.

But I get the following error:

*This command requires you to be logged in to https://some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/

You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`*

My user `.npmrc` file:

```
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/:keyfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.key.pem.   
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/:certfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.crt.pem
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<auth_token>
```

My project `.npmrc` file:

```
 @fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/.  
 @scope1:registry=https://some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/   
 @scope2:registry=https://some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path2/  
 //npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=<auth_token>   
 //some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/:_auth=<auth>   
 strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: To publish an NPM package via CLI, you need to log in first. I assume you already created an account on the npm registry, so just log in with that username and password and it will work.

Comment: I tried to login, I've recevied the OTP code via email, entered it but without results.

Comment: If I run `npm whoami`, I get the username I've created, so I'm assuming I'm logged in.

Comment: I added a few useful commands, as I cannot post those as comments. Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To publish a package to NPM you need to login to the NPM registry. Here are a few steps to do that-

### Login to NPM

- If you are not registered

```
npm adduser
```

- If you are already registered

```
npm login
```

- If you are already logged in and want to verify the user

```
npm whoami
```

### Build and publish

- Create a build

```
npm run build-library
```

- Publish to NPM

```
npm publish --access public
```

Comment: So after I ran `npm whoami`, I get my username. It means the login is successful. But after I run `npm publish`, I get the same error with `npm adduser`.

Comment: Did you try the last command, `npm publish --access public`

Comment: Yes, with the same result. What I'm seeing in the error is that is not refering to the `registry.npmjs.org`, but to the nexus repository we use as a wrapper to the `registry.npmjs.org`. So do I also need to be logged in on nexus or something?

Comment: See this answer, if it helps- https://stackoverflow.com/q/57279087/11834856

Comment: Seems like you are trying to publish the package privately. Is it?

Comment: Yes! I'm looking now on the stackoverflow question you sent.

Comment: If I try to add an user on the private registry, I get `web login is not supported`. 
`npm adduser --registry=https://some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/`

Comment: Give it a read- https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages

Comment: On it, I need to understand more of this `scopes`, `registried`, `auth` stuff. I will come back if I found anything. Thanks!

Comment: Where can I find my user name to insert in `npm adduser`?

Comment: If you already have an account created, this command will ask for your existing username, otherwise, you can create a new user with this same command. To verify if you are already logged in, run `npm whoami`. For more information, read this- https://medium.com/easy-coding/convert-a-single-file-component-into-a-vue-library-and-publish-it-to-npm-b0f10f479a04

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is that we need to add the certificate and key files in the `global .npmrc` on repo level, not on the nexus level:

```
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/:keyfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.key.pem   
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/:certfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.crt.pem
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path2/:keyfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.key.pem   
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path2/:certfile=/Users/<host>/Documents/Certificates/npm.crt.pem
```

Same for the `project .npmrc`:

```
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path1/:_auth=<auth>                        
//some-package.com:48082/nexus/repository/path2/:_auth=<auth>
```

Answer (score -1):

I just deleted my .npmrc in nodejs 20, and everything works fine.