# NPM login to GitHub registry requires lowercase username

Tags: github, npm, npm-cli

I'm trying to log in from the command line using this command:

```sh
$ npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

But my username on GitHub has an uppercase first letter, which results in the following error:

```sh
$ npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
Username: <Username>
npm WARN Name must be lowercase
```

Anyone know how I can get around this? Do I have to change my GitHub username for this to work?

Comment: What happens if you enter it all lowercase?

Comment: That results in a "401 Unauthorized" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm started to enforce lower case usernames at some points, leaving the accounts previously created in this awkward situation.

To solve the issue, you might want to email support@npmjs.com, which will link the lowercase variant of your username to your account.

source: this [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1787).

Comment: Aren't they just going to say "you're trying to log in to GitHub, not us"?

Comment: I guess we'll find out :/ But aren't they the same company now?

Comment: lol, they did  A very helpful support person named Jude suggested I go to github.com/login to login to my Github account ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Use `GitHub` token instead of credentials:

[Stack Overflow: Set NPM credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271202)

Don't forget to set `Read packages` permission upon creation.