# Environment variables in dependabot.yml?

Tags: npm, gitlab, dependabot, npm-registry

I'm trying to set up [dependabot-standalone](https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot-standalone) to run in a GitLab-CI pipeline in a private instance.

It's an npm package and I'm using a private npm registry to fetch my dependencies from. According to the [docs](https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot-standalone#configuration), I should set up my registry access data within the `.gitlab/dependabot.yml` file.

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#registries) for settings in `dependabot.yml` clearly say how to set up the credentials to access a given registry:

```yaml
registries:
  npm-npmjs:
    type: npm-registry
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org
    username: octocat
    password: ${{secrets.MY_NPM_PASSWORD}}  # Must be an unencoded password
```

```yaml
registries:
  npm-github:
    type: npm-registry
    url: https://npm.pkg.github.com
    token: ${{secrets.MY_GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN}}
```

But only for its use in GitHub with project `secrets`. **Is there a way to use GitLab's custom defined CI/CD variables instead?**

So far I have unsuccessfully tried to use `${{CI_PRIVATE_NPM_ACCESS_TOKEN}}` and `${CI_PRIVATE_NPM_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

Answer (score 0):

I think [npm-login-noninteractive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-login-noninteractive) could be helpful in this case.

```yaml
job-name:
  script:
    - npm install -g npm-login-noninteractive
    - NPM_USER=testUser NPM_PASS=testPass NPM_EMAIL=test@example.com NPM_REGISTRY=your.npm.com npm-login-noninteractive
```

Other possible useful answers, here: [How to set npm credentials using `npm login` without reading from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460980/how-to-set-npm-credentials-using-npm-login-without-reading-from-stdin)

---

According to this [example](https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot-standalone), you need to set the following environment variables within GitLab:

- `SETTINGS__GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN`
- `SETTINGS__GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN`

To set these variables at the project level, within GitLab go to: Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables.

Comment: I have `SETTINGS__GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN` properly defined. According to [docs](https://gitlab.com/dependabot-gitlab/dependabot/-/blob/master/doc/environment.md#access) the second one is only needed to prevent _run into rate limits when fetching changelog and release notes for all dependencies which code comes from github_. So I don't think that is related to the problem of not being able to fetch dependencies from the configured npm registry.