npm publish not working with gitlab ci and nexus package repository
i have a .gitlab-ci.yml file, trying to build and publish a simple react-vite-typescript package,
the build stage succeeds but the the publish stage fails with the "error code ENEEDAUTH". i am using a node:20 image, and copying the locally working ".npmrc" file to the image.
stages:
  - build
  - publish

variables:
  NEXUS_REPO_URL_PRIVATE: "http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-private/"
  NEXUS_REPO_URL_GROUP : "http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-group/"
  NEXUS_USERNAME: "npm-private-user"
  NEXUS_EMAIL: "private-user@gmail.com"

image: 127.0.0.1:8082/node:latest

build-dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd Src
    - npm install 
    - npm run build 
    - npx tsc
  only:
    - main

publish-dev:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - cd Src
    - npm config set registry "http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-private/"
    - npm config set //localhost:8081/repository/npm-private/:_auth YWRtaW46MTIz
    - echo '//localhost:8081/repository/npm-private/:_auth="YWRtaW46MTIz"' > .npmrc
    - echo "registry=http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-private/" >> .npmrc
    - npm publish --registry http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-private/
  only:
    - main
  dependencies:
    - build-dev

and as you can see, i'am using every possible way to login to the registry, but no luck, i get this error:
npm error code ENEEDAUTH
npm error need auth This command requires you to be logged in to http://192.168.1.113:8081/repository/npm-private/
npm error need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`


i also tested doing as this post suggests, but the npm adduser (or npm login) command doesn't accepts password like that and get stuck in password section.

If you setup the .npmrc file, you don't need to call adduser or login. Did you try that? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014522/442837

that was my go to solution at first, i built a custom docker image which copied an already functioning  .npmrc file from the build context, but no luck
